# Adding vertex into polyline at interval using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, vertices

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 version and I have polyline features, for this I have to add vertex at some distance (10mtr) and label the z value of that vertex.

Is there any tool or script available?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [Densify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm) which

> Adds vertices along line or polygon features. Also replaces curve
> segments (Bezier, circular arcs, and elliptical arcs) with line
> segments.

Comment: But i have to label the z value of that particular vertex which generated or inserted vertex.

Comment: @PreethiR, If you are happy for interpolated values for vertices created by the Densify tool then have a look at this [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Feature_To_3D_By_Attribute/00q90000002z000000/)?